# Get Gmail Contacts from into C# desktop form

Tags: c#, gmail

I am trying to get the contacts of Gmail in to C# desktop form application, i have used the google APi for this purpose, i want to show the contacts of gmail in gridview as the button is pressed. but as the button is pressed nothing is displayed in grid view.

The code is pasted below.

Please let me know and help me to resolve this issue.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void FetchContactList()
    {
        // Define string of list
        List<string> lstContacts = new List<string>();

        // Below requestsetting class take 3 parameters applicationname, gmail username, gmail password. Provide appropriate Gmail account details
        RequestSettings rsLoginInfo = new RequestSettings("", "suryabg2000@gmail.com", "XXXXXX");
        rsLoginInfo.AutoPaging = true;
        ContactsRequest cRequest = new ContactsRequest(rsLoginInfo);

        // fetch contacts list
        Feed<Contact> feedContacts = cRequest.GetContacts();

        // looping the feedcontact entries
        try
        {
            foreach (Contact gmailAddresses in feedContacts.Entries)
            {
                // Looping to read email addresses
                foreach (EMail emailId in gmailAddresses.Emails)
                {
                    lstContacts.Add(emailId.Address);
                }
            }
            // finally binding the list to gridview defined in above step

           // dataGridView1.DataSource = lstContacts;
           ////dataGridView1.DataBind();
           ////dataGridView1.DataSource = dataGridView1;
           // dataGridView1.Show();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error Please enter the correct credentials","Error",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            //throw;
        }

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<MyClass> lstContacts = new List<MyClass>();
        //lstContacts.Add(new MyClass() { Id = 1, Email = "def@gmail.com" });
        //lstContacts.Add(new MyClass() { Id = 2, Email = "def@gmail.com" });
        //lstContacts.Add(new MyClass() { Id = 3, Email = "ghi@gmail.com" });

        dataGridView1.DataSource = new BindingSource(lstContacts, null);
        dataGridView1.Show();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<MyClass> lstContacts = new List<MyClass>();
    //need to add items to list
    lstContacts.Add(new MyClass() { Id = 1, Email = "def@gmail.com" }); 
    lstContacts.Add(new MyClass() { Id = 2, Email = "def@gmail.com" });
    lstContacts.Add(new MyClass() { Id = 3, Email = "ghi@gmail.com" });

    dataGridView1.DataSource = lstContacts;
    dataGridView1.Show();

 }
```

I'd suggest that you step through code first and that should give you a better idea what exactly is causing grid view empty results. It might be problems from calling Google Contacts API or from binding data to your gridview control.

But just by looking at your click event handler, I can't help asking why you commented out lstContacts.Add lines. The list, `lstContacts`, is still empty, isn't it?

Also, I'd use `dataGridView1.DataSource = lstContacts` instead, for data binding.

EDIT:
The code certainly worked for me. 3 rows were shown here.

Examples:

Use Wrapper Class

```
public class StringValue
{
    public StringValue(string s)
    {
        _value = s;
    }
    public string Value { get { return _value; } set { _value = value; } }
    string _value;
}
List<StringValue> lstContacts = new List<StringValue>();
lstContacts.Add("your email address");
dataGridView1.DataSource = lstContacts;
dataGridView1.Show();
```

Use DataTable

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Email Address");

dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "def@gmail.com" });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "def@gmail.com" });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "def@gmail.com" });
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
dataGridView1.Show();
```

Comment: i am new to C# programming!!! i have used your recommendations of dataGridView!.DataSource = lstContacts... but still the lstContacts is empty. and its not showing me anything in the grid view!!! Please help me!

Comment: what happens if you uncomment those lines? Or you could try using a new List with different type, say string type. List<string> lstTest = new List<string>(); lstTest.Add("abc"); dataGridView1.DataSource = lstTest;

Comment: Give it a try see if that would give you any results or not.

Comment: i have tried to impart the parameters of RequestSettings rsLoginInfo = new RequestSettings("",emailtb.text,tbpassword.text); now it gives me the length of the contacts... and grid view gives me only one column and that is length!!!!

Comment: Yep, that's what's expected! Because you are using List<string>.

Comment: So to see your emails, you can try 2 things: 1) use linq: dataGridView1.DataSource = lstContacts.Select(x => new { Value = x }).ToList(); 2) create a wrapper class, and make list of that wrapper class

Comment: Actually there's 3rd approach, which you can use DataTable to store your list of contacts, and bind it to your datagridview.

Comment: Thanks alot woodykiddy!!!! it really worked as smoothly as it worked in your machine! thanks a lot :)

Comment: Happy to help. Would also appreciate it if you could mark the answer.

Comment: i would have done that!!! but i am new to stackover flow and you have to wait until my reputation is 15!!! but i promise to do that once my reputation is up to the mark!!!!!

Comment: woodykiddy Boss!!! i have tried the data table and it is getting data and displaying it... but in only one line all the email are displayed! please help me to sort this!!!!

Answer (score 1):

i have fetched the contacts of gmail to C# desktop application with the help of below mentioned code. used the GOOGLE API for the purpose!!!
The correct and working code with dataset is pasted below.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void fetchContactList()
    {
        // Define string of list
        List<string> lstContacts = new List<string>();



        // Below requestsetting class take 3 parameters applicationname, gmail username, gmail password. Provide appropriate Gmail account details
        RequestSettings rsLoginInfo = new RequestSettings("", textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);
        rsLoginInfo.AutoPaging = true;
        ContactsRequest cRequest = new ContactsRequest(rsLoginInfo);

        // fetch contacts list
        Feed<Contact> feedContacts = cRequest.GetContacts();


        //dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 1;
        //dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Product ID";



        // looping the feedcontact entries
        try
        {
           // dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Name", "Name");
            RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
            string email = "";
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Email Address");
            foreach (Contact gmailAddresses in feedContacts.Entries)
            {
                // Looping to read email addresses
                foreach (EMail emailId in gmailAddresses.Emails)
                {
                   dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {email=emailId.Address});
                   dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;  
                }

                dataGridView1.Show();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error Please enter the correct credentials","Error",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            //throw;
        }

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        fetchContactList();

    }

}
```

}